# Return value from Sequence using JPQL

Tags: java, persistence, jpql

I am trying to use a Sequence in SQL on an Oracle Database to retrieve an ID before I run a query. But for some reason it never returns an integer for me that I can use. Just null.

The SQL query have been tested to work before I decided to do the application with this Netbeans Persistency approach.

```
    Query idRes = manager
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT seq_bug.nextval from dual");
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    idRes.executeUpdate();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    int id = (Integer) idRes.getParameterValue(0);

    Query q = manager.
            createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO REPORTEDBUG"
                            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    q.setParameter(1, id);
    q.setParameter(2, author);
    q.setParameter(3, bugtype);
    q.setParameter(4, component);
    q.setParameter(5, sysversion);
    q.setParameter(6, priority);
    q.setParameter(7, assignedto);
    q.setParameter(8, status);
    q.setParameter(9, desc);
    q.executeUpdate();
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I guess I am just placing `int id = (Integer) idRes.getParameterValue(0);` wrong but I can't figure out what else it could be.

Comment: Why not just "INSERT INTO REPORTEDBUG VALUES (seq_bug.nextval, ?, ?, ...)"? As for your example I'm not sure if it is ok to finish transaction before retrieving results.

Comment: I could try that of course. Otherwise I made sort of a hack-ish solution where I get a BigDecimal, extract the Long and then cast that as Integer.